# Repair/Rebuild master.mdf in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, database, restore, rebuild, repair

Does anyone have or know where I can find the tools or information to repair/rebuild the master database for Microsoft SQL Server 2000? I'm assuming is that is what I need to do based on the following error and that the service will not start.

Thank you

```
2012-08-08 13:59:55.10 server    Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 17 2002 14:22:05 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
    Desktop Engine on Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

2012-08-08 13:59:55.10 server    Copyright (C) 1988-2002 Microsoft Corporation.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.12 server    All rights reserved.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.12 server    Server Process ID is 640.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.12 server    Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.12 server    SQL Server is starting at priority class 'normal'(2 CPUs detected).
2012-08-08 13:59:55.59 server    SQL Server configured for thread mode processing.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.59 server    Using dynamic lock allocation. [500] Lock Blocks, [1000] Lock Owner Blocks.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.64 spid4     Starting up database 'master'.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.64 spid4     Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2012-08-08 13:59:55.64 spid4     Cannot recover the master database. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a backup of the master database, rebuild the master database so you can start the sql server. Do so in single user mode (sqlserver.exe -c -m), and then restore the backup.

If you do not have a backup, you will have to rebuild the master database, and then manually (or by means of scripts if you happen to have your databases and logins scripted) re-add the databases and logins.

Rebuilding your master database:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/recover-the-master-database-in-sql-server/5025441